# How to backup Android Wallet?

Tags: client, thin-clients, bitcoin-wallet-app

I'm finally getting ready to install an Android client.
I believe [Android Wallet](https://market.android.com/details?id=de.schildbach.wallet) is the most popular one.

How do I back up the bitcoins stored on it?

Also, is there a thin native Android client being developed?

Comment: foldersync looks good to backup into my owncloud webdav. But which folders do i have to backup to be able to restore bitcoin wallet?

Comment: P.S. I ended up using the Android version of Blockchain's MyWallet, which has built in backup to email/dropbox/google drive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a known way to export my wallet private key from the "Bitcoin Android" app (com.bitcoinandroid)?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3247/is-there-a-known-way-to-export-my-wallet-private-key-from-the-bitcoin-android)

Comment: Andreas, once stored, how does this "private key" work as a backup tool? If my phone is lost, how can I retrieve the balance that was in the android wallet on my pc for example?

Comment: @Tom - most clients support importing a private key (how to do this is client-specific)

Comment: I don´t consider SD-card to be external storage. Is it possible to backup to a connected PC or a cloud service

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bitcoin Wallet for Android supports backing up your private keys to external storage (e.g. SD Card). Just select "Export/Import private keys" from the action bar overflow menu.

Comment: Just to note v4.3.2 (not sure when it changed) of [bitcoin wallet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.schildbach.wallet) backup wallet/restore wallet are in safety menu which can be found in the  overflow menu.

Answer (score 2):

As with any backup solution you must test it yourself through the whole cycle first in a zero risk scenario.

[Mycelium](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mycelium.wallet) has an [excellent backup solution](https://www.mycelium.com/wallet/FAQ.html#q011) which outputs a [seed phrase for a HD wallet](https://bitcoin.org/en/glossary/hd-wallet-seed)

You can then store this any way you wish, for example on paper in a physically secure location.

Comment: I think I'll wait for a good light client. I just wanted to play around with some coins on my android, but it's not urgent (I really don't have anywhere to spend them anyway at this point).

Comment: Yes it takes an age to get started, even on a wifi connection. I think mine took over 24 hours. But after that it's sweet and I like to keep a few on there just in case. There are people beginning to accept them, and I couldn't miss the opportunity. Sometimes it's scary when the wallet becomes worth more than the hardware though! :-)

Comment: Things change a lot since the first answer, updated.