# How to decode private key from Android Bitcoin Wallet?

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core, bitcoin-wallet-app

I want to import my private key from the android's Bitcoin Wallet (the one created by Andreas Schildbach) but it can export it only in an encrypted way.

How do I decrypt the file so I can import the key to my Bitcoin Qt?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a known way to export my wallet private key from the "Bitcoin Android" app (com.bitcoinandroid)?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3247/is-there-a-known-way-to-export-my-wallet-private-key-from-the-bitcoin-android)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

from: https://github.com/schildbach/bitcoin-wallet/tree/master/wallet

```
The backup file is encrypted using your chosen password. You can use OpenSSL to decrypt:

openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -in <filename>
```

Comment: The instructions have been moved to: https://github.com/bitcoin-wallet/bitcoin-wallet/blob/master/wallet/README.recover.md

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is trying this in 2017, openssl has now defaulted to use SHA256 instead of the MD5 assumed in the older answers. Add "-md md5" (no quotes) to your openssl command line string.

https://superuser.com/questions/1245384/openssl-bad-decrypt-between-0-9-8o-and-1-1-0f

For example, originally without that MD5 option I was seeing:

```
$openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -in bitcoin-wallet-backup-2017-09-28 -out decrypted
enter aes-256-cbc decryption password: ******
bad decrypt
140031244338432:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:../crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:535:
```

But then with the MD5 option:

```
$openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -in bitcoin-wallet-backup-2017-09-28 -out decrypted -md md5
enter aes-256-cbc decryption password: ******
```

It runs successfully and creates a file called "decrypted" which is mostly binary data but starts with ^Vorg.bitcoin.production^R and contains your 12 word mnemonic as text near the top of the file.

Comment: In this case simply use the openssl-1.0 bindings which enforces the old encoding that changed when using recent version 2 binaries:

    openssl-1.0 enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -in bitcoin-wallet-backup-2017-09-28

Comment: I got a warning `*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
` but the decryption of the secret keys worked fine, though!

Answer (score 1):

This script seems to do the work

https://github.com/jleni/wallet-decrypt

You just need to create a backup and it will give you back a mnemonic that you can use in electrum or electrum cash.

Answer (score 0):

This guide was the only one that worked for me. The mnemonic phrase didn't work on Electrum nor Electron Cash, but the exported private key as described here did:

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=2061691.0

Answer (score -1):

I go a bit fancier:

```
set /p xin=
set xout="%xin%.txt"
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -in "%XIN%" -out %XOUT%
```

But basically you want to name a file for the output and also the -k flag allows **PASSWORD** directly to be entered, like so:

openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -in "**INFILE**" -out "**OUTFILE**.txt" -k **PASSWORD** ,

where **CAPS** is the variable. Save above 3 lines or single openssl cmd into a *.bat (WinBatch file)

Comment: Im not understand about " save above 3 lines or . . . . " because my result outfile.txt words cannot read . Excample " ãí`âVÏ7@ãí`âVÏ7@ " Thank you .

Comment: @SekeratKejunG See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f88486d1d2a6616d5328). The 3 lines are a batch file. You can just skip straight to `openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -in "encrypted" -out "decrypted.txt"`. `encrypted` is the base64 AES encrypted text file, `decrypted.txt` will be a Litecoin wallet in text. If the files in the gist decrypt but your wallet isn't decrypting, then something else is wrong