# Restore android wallet on a mac

Tags: client, electrum, wallet-recovery, multibit-hd

Ok, so I have this bitcoin wallet backup.

- I have the 12 word seed
- I have *a* password
- I have a number in this format ****/** that I wrote down.

I made this backup on an android tablet. Not sure which app. I *think* "Bitcoin Wallet", which is android only, apparently.

I obviously would like to restore it, but I don't own anything android anymore. Any way I can do this on any Mac/iOS app?

- I tried putting my backup in Electrum's wallet folder, with no success.
- I tried decrypting it as described [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/49023/how-to-restore-from-backup-of-android-bitcoin-wallet). Not sure what I'm supposed to do with the "decrypted" file that is as unreadable as the original.

help.

**Update** : I tried restoring with Multibit, which I read was compatible with Android Bitcoin Wallet because *bitcoinj*. Multibit accepted my seed and the ****/** number as a timestamp, did not recognize the backup file (which according to MB docs is not a big deal) and went on an all-night journey to 'sync' with the network.

In the morning I had a new wallet with 0 bitcoins in it.

Does this mean my wallet was empty all along? That I'm using the wrong seed? That I just need to find an old Android phone to try again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do:

- Find/borrow an android device (from a friend, relative, co-worker, etc)
- Install the Bitcoin software you used to have
- Restore the wallet from the seed (when restoring from a seed, in most cases the password isn't needed, because you can set a new password after the restoration of the seed)
- Make a new transaction and transfer all bitcoins to the new wallet address on iOS/OSx

Caution! **The seed is the most important thing** you have. Don't show/give the seed to anyone because they can recreate the wallet!