# Cannot recover my wallet

Tags: backup

I have an Android backup that I am sure I am using the right password. I have exported the file, and trying to decrypt it with openssl:

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -md md5 -a -in ./backup_carteira_2017
```

or

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -in ./backup_carteira_2017
```

I fill in the password when prompted and it seems to decrypt as I don't get a "bad decrypt", however the output is not readable at all. Any password different from the right one throws a bad decrypt error.

Am I missing anything here?

The backup has been generated in Jun, 2017, not sure if this matters.

Regards,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restore from backup of Android Bitcoin Wallet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/49023/how-to-restore-from-backup-of-android-bitcoin-wallet) where the software author explains the proper process.

Comment: Note: Anyone reading [https://github.com/bitcoin-wallet/.../README.recover.md](https://github.com/bitcoin-wallet/bitcoin-wallet/blob/master/wallet/README.recover.md) should probably **PAY CAREFUL ATTENTION TO THE FIRST SENTENCE** there. If you proceed beyond that, note that the output of the SSL command is *not expected to be readable*.