# Bitcoin Wallet for Android - Issues decrypting the wallet backup BIN file using OpenSSL

Tags: android, bitcoin-wallet-app

I've followed the advice found [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/17176/how-to-decode-private-key-from-android-bitcoin-wallet) and also on the [Github article](https://github.com/bitcoin-wallet/bitcoin-wallet/blob/master/wallet/README.recover.md) linked from that post, but I'm still having issues decrypted a wallet backup using the latest version of Bitcoin Wallet on Android (v5.26 released 7/28/17)

I was able to take the BIN file in question and import that between Bitcoin Android wallets, so I know the backup is not corrupted and the password works.

When I run the `openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -in <filename>` command, targeting the BIN backup file, it prompts for the password, which is inputted. The resulting decryption fails.

Is there a change made to the encryption algorithm that I'm not taking into account? Any/all help is appreciated.

Thank you

EDIT: To be clear, I also attempted the `openssl` command string found on the Github article, but that also fails (it includes the `-md md5` parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i managed to decrypt a backup by doing this  :

openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -md md5 -a -in ./walletbackupfile > decrypted_wallet

however, i have not managed to getting at the private keys from the output.

i have tried wallet-tool dump --dump-privkeys --password=..pin

but it seems like no private keys are dumped in the output

i have also tried wallet-tool raw-dump --dump-privkeys   --password=..pin

that seems to dump some encrypted private keys of some kind, but i am not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.. I was naive and didn't follow each step from that Github link, but after loading the bitcoinj `wallet-tool` I was able to successfully dump the private keys.