# Unable to decrypt wallet.wallet file

Tags: wallet-recovery

I have a wallet.wallet file that I *think* was created with Android bitcoin wallet or Multibit.  It's base64 encoded.

Putting it in a decoder, it gives me this information, redacted just in case:

{"iv":"randomalphanumeric==","v":1,"iter":1000,"ks":256,"ts":64,"mode":"ccm","adata":"","cipher":"aes","salt":"randomalphanumeric=","ct":"randomalphanumeric="}

When I try to upload any part of that, including just the raw base64, into Electrum (the recommended alternative since multibit was deprecated) I get errors that its invalid.  The android bitcoin app either can't read it or I don't know my password.

Does anyone have any idea what this is or what its for? Is it even cryptocurrency related?

Also, the last string has a ton of characters including forward slash "/" and plus signs "+". Not sure if that helps.

I did attempt to try and follow with this thread [Bitcoin Wallet for Android - Issues decrypting the wallet backup BIN file using OpenSSL](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57487/bitcoin-wallet-for-android-issues-decrypting-the-wallet-backup-bin-file-using) , but to no avail.
I get "error reading input file"

Answer (score 1):

> **Does anyone have any idea what this is or what its for?**

It is obviously related to cryptography.

Since the Bitcoin network itself doesn't use encryption, this is likely a configuration file or data file for a specific wallet's scheme of encrypting the private-keys and other information that need to be protected from being stolen and misused.

```
{ 
  "iv":"randomalphanumeric==",
  "v":1,
  "iter":1000,
  "ks":256,
  "ts":64,
  "mode":"ccm",
  "adata":"",
  "cipher":"aes",
  "salt":"randomalphanumeric=",
  "ct":"randomalphanumeric="
}
```

`iv` is [initialisation vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector)
`v` is version
`iter` is number of iterations of encryption to be applied
`ks` is key size
`ts` don't know, maybe the size of something.
`mode` is an encryption mode. `ccm` is probably something like [cipher chaining mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCM_mode)?
`cipher` is the encryption algorithm. `aes` is the "[advanced encryption standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)".
`salt` is a [random number used to combat attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) using precomputed dictionaries.
`ct` don't know. Could be ["ciphertext"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext) - the encrypted version of some data ("plaintext").

---

> **the last string has a ton of characters including forward slash "/" and plus signs "+"**

That is fairly common in encoding methods used to take binary data and present it using readable/printable characters. In this case it is probably [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Base64_table) encoding. As I think you know, encoding is not encryption, just an easily reversible presentation method.

---

By itself, it is of no use to you. If you know the password (encryption key) you could probably decrypt the possible ciphertext (ct value) after reversing the base64 encoding. You could then examine the (potentially binary) "plaintext" to see if it contains a Bitcoin private key.

Comment: Alright, I think I know the password.  Is there a tool available to decrypt?