# What went wrong transferring my BCC out of Bitcoin Wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-cash, bitcoin-wallet-app

On the day of the fork, I had my BTC in [Bitcoin Wallet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.schildbach.wallet&hl=en) on Android. I sent my BTC to a new wallet. I then made a backup of my old wallet, moved it to my computer, and decrypted it using `openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -in` as described [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/29519/57374). The resulting file was mostly unreadable, but it had a 12-word mnemonic at the top. I entered it into a local copy of https://iancoleman.github.io/bip39/. I selected the BIP44 tab and and copied the value from "account extended private key" which began with `xprv`.

I installed Electron Cash on my phone and imported the key. It said the import was successful, but I'm seeing 0 BCC in my wallet. I've also followed the instructions [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57422/how-to-sweep-private-extended-key-from-mycellium-into-coinomi-for-bitcoin-cash-c/) for checking my balance on blockdozer.info and importing my key into Coinomi, and both of those methods agree that there's no BCC associated with that address / key.

**Questions**:

1. Is there any other export process I should try, or should these definitely have worked?
2. Is there any possible way for a wallet that had BTC in it from Jul 28 - Aug 13 to not have had BCC associated with it?
3. Is there any way to look backward and find out if that wallet ever had BCC, and if so what happened to it?

Comment: Exactly the same experience using wallet-tool to get WIF and import into to electron cash. Valid keys but ends with a single transaction which appears to empty the wallet.

Answer (score 1):

Your start with BIP39 was good.

You can check your Bitcoin Cash funds according to the explanation at: [How to sweep private extended key from mycellium into coinomi for bitcoin cash coins?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57422/how-to-sweep-private-extended-key-from-mycellium-into-coinomi-for-bitcoin-cash-c/)

There you can understand your funds in internal and external addresses and how to sweep them into a wallet which in this case is Coinomi.

Comment: When I follow those instructions, blockdozer and Coinomi both say there's no BCC associated with that key / address. I've updated my question and would appreciate any help with figuring out what happened.

Comment: If you enter the internal and external first 2-3 addresses you get from the BIP39 page at https://blockchain.info/ - do you see the amounts on the BTC blockchain? Then you should see these amounts on BCC as well - in case they were there before Aug 1st.

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems you're performing needless complex steps. Let's start here: Are you testing the original BTC address (which held BTC during the fork) or the BTC address you sent the funds to, when looking in the dozer explorer?
2. No.
3. Yes, simply paste the BTC address that contained BTC during the fork in the dozer explorer.

In Coinomi, you need to sweep the original btc address private key as a BCH key, in a newly created BCH wallet (Overview tab, Click on .../Sweep Wallet)

Comment: 1) I'm testing the address for the original wallet, which held the BTC during the fork. This is what's showing a balance of 0 BCC.

Comment: Do you see the unspent BTC amounts on the BTC blockchain before Aug 1st? Then there should be the same in BCC.

Answer (score 0):

You made a common mistake: In Electron Cash, you should choose a BCC server manually, otherwise it chooses a BTC server and it doesn't show your BCC balance.

Comment: Is this the "server used to query your history" under the Network menu? That originally defaulted to electron.cornucopia.io and choosing other options from the menu doesn't seem to affect anything. Should I be looking somewhere else?

Comment: @octern Try choosing `electroncash.bitcoinplug.com`, right click it and then choose `use it as server`

Comment: I've switched to that server (using the Android client; the desktop version won't run on my computer). Nothing appears different.